# How to select specific data in a large json file and save the result with same structure

Tags: json, select, bigdata, jq

Very large Json file (3Gb) like this:

```
  {
    "listPoint": [{
            "Paime": "RE6845",
            "rmOi": "SNO-55",
            "State": "OPEN",
            "dateOpneing": "2017-12-22",
            "adress": {
                "ZIPCODE": "33410",
                "codeRoc": "33105"
            }
        },

        {
            "Paime": "RE6243",
            "rmOi": "SNO-65",
            "State": "OPEN",
            "dateOpneing": "2014-11-12",
            "adress": {
                "ZIPCODE": "453410",
                "codeRoc": "35105"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

I'm Trying to filter it to another file with same structure, the condition is that all ZIPCODES must belong to a specific list:

```
  ['33410', '42000', '75015'....]
```

the result should be like this (the output file must have the same structure as the input):

```
 {
        "listPoint": [{
                "Paime": "RE6845",
                "rmOi": "SNO-55",
                "State": "OPEN",
                "dateOpneing": "2017-12-22",
               "adress": {
                "ZIPCODE": "33410",
                "codeRoc": "35105"
            },
    
            {
                "Paime": "RE6243",
                "rmOi": "SNO-65",
                "State": "OPEN",
                "dateOpneing": "2014-11-12",
                "ZIPCODE": "75015",
                "codeRoc": "55115"
            }
        .....
    
        ]
    }
```

Ive Tried by this but it streams all the file:

```
./jq-win64.exe -n --stream 'fromstream(0|truncate_stream(inputs))' test1.json
```

I dont know how to do this  please can you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If your computer has enough RAM, then the simplest solution would be along the lines of:

```
< very-large-file.json jq '
  .listPoint |= map(select(.ZIPCODE|startswith("33")))'
```

(2) Otherwise, you could use jq's streaming parser in a two-step solution such as:

```
< very-large-file.json jq -n --stream '
    fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs))
    | select(.ZIPCODE|startswith("33"))' |
  jq -s '{listPoint: .}'
```

In the first step, a stream of the relevant JSON objects is produced; in the second step, these are re-assembled into the desired structure.

(3) If even the winnowed array is too large to fit into memory, then you could do worse than:

```
echo '{listPoint:'
< very-large-file.json jq -n --stream '
    fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs))
    | select(.ZIPCODE|startswith("33"))' |
  jq -ncr 'input, (inputs | ",", .)'
echo '}'
```

(4) If you want to select zipcodes based on a whitelist, change the selection criterion e.g. to

```
.ZIPCODE|IN($whitelist[])
```

——-

Note: if your shell is not sufficiently bash-like, you might find it better to use the following invocation format:

```
jq OPTIONS -f program.jq INPUT.json
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks, 
there was a mistake in the json , so i fixed it with jsonlint.com.
 after that i used the command you said but it gives an error with powershell : 
The '<' operator is reserved for future use, please can you help?

and when i use the first command it gives also an arror : 
  jq: error (at <stdin>:2206): startswith() requires string inputs

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: If ZIPCODE is sometimes numeric, you would need to modify the test to include an invocation of `tostring`

Comment: Hello peak thank you for your response, I updated the question I've tried many things and only streaming the whoal file has worked , please can you help? regards,

Comment: See (4) re $whitelist

Comment: Thanks peak for your help,  my json file has changed , the zip code is now in an " adress" object. please can you change the parsing commands according to this and with the whitelist?  regards,

Comment: Sorry, but once a question has been asked and answered, the Q should not be changed arbitrarily.  If you have a new question, by all means ask it, but if it's just a small variation of the original question, please be sure to try to adjust the original answer appropriately.

Comment: Hello, just for your information i fixed my issue by the option "test".

Answer (score 0):

For the record, another way to avoid issues with the size of the file would be to use a companion tool such as [jm](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm) (a wrapper script for JSON Machine) or [jm.py](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm) (a wrapper script for the ijson Python library):

```
jm --pointer /listPoint large.json |
  jq -n '["33410", "42000", "75015"] as $ok
         | {listPoint: [inputs | select(.adress.ZIPCODE|IN($ok[]))]} '
```

or

```
jm.py -i listPoint.item large.json |
  jq -n '["33410", "42000", "75015"] as $ok
         | {listPoint: [inputs | select(.adress.ZIPCODE|IN($ok[]))]} '
```

I usually find `jm` to be significantly more economical with both time and space, but it takes a bit of work to install it.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of these two wrapper scripts, which were created precisely for handling cases such as this.